# regex, replace all matches but once

Tags: javascript

let me explain my problem, i have this code so far:

```
post.contentHtml().replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, '')
```

that strip ALL html tag from the output and replace with ''.

Now the problem is that a post can contain multiple tag, so if someone post an image or embed like:

```
<p><iframe data-s9e-mediaembed="twitter" allow="au…t:250px;max-width:550px;width:100%"></iframe></p>
```

the result is this:

what i'm want to achieve is to show only ONE icon per element, or simply 1 icon. Is that possible

post.contentHtml output is:

```
ContentHtml: '<p><iframe data-s9e-mediaembed="twitter" allow="au…t:250px;max-width:550px;width:100%"></iframe></p>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quantify the regular expression so it will match multiple times in a row.

```
post.contentHtml().replace(/(<\/?[^>]+(>|$))+/g, '')
```

`pattern+` matches a sequence of 1 or more matches of `pattern`

Comment: this works really fine, can you explain how it works, just to understand

Comment: `+` means to match the previous pattern 1 or more consecutive times. This is one of the most basic regexp features.